# How to get spring datasoure properties value from AWS parameter store?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

In my spring boot application, I've maintained spring.datasource.url in the application.properties file. I need the URL/user & password to be secured and the values are available in the AWS parameter store. I have referenced this [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_parameter_store) for simply added a dependency on the (*spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config*) starter module to activate the support. I actually don't know how the configuration parameters will be maintained and how to retrieve the parameter store value into my project.

How can I achieve this without using the hardcoded value from the following (application.properties) properties?

```
spring.datasource.url= url
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

To use AWS System Manager Parameter Store as a `PropertySource` in a Spring Boot application do the following steps.

Add the following dependencies to the `build.gradle`:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config'
}
```

Add to the `src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties` the property specifying the application name:

```
spring.application.name=my-app
```

By default Spring Cloud AWS relies on the [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) and [DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/regions/DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.html).

If application runs **not** on EC2/Fargate instance, configure AWS credentials and region either by setting the following environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_REGION=us-west-1
```

Or make sure you have valid AWS configuration files `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`.

Define the following properties in the AWS System Manager Parameter Store:

```
/config/my-app/spring.datasource.url
/config/my-app/spring.datasource.username
/config/my-app/spring.datasource.password
```

Comment: Is there possible to process AWS credentials from the AWS parameter store? Because we are in staging environment we don't use the configuration from an EC2 machine

Comment: AWS credentials and region must be specified in environment variables, system properties or files (~/.aws/credentials). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html

Comment: If the application is running in the aws cloud(EC2/Fargate) , then spring-cloud is smart enough to get aws credentials. we dont need to configure any environment variables or ~/.aws/* . Make sure you have spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure dependency added

Comment: Spring Cloud doesn't configure AWS credentials, it relies on [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) that does it best to find AWS credentials provider. See the Javadoc.